# Programmatically Hide an Android App in Launcher?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I'm having trouble understanding PackageManager it seems. For this example I want to hide google talk app from the default launcher. Any help would be appreciated :)

In my Main Activity.java

```
if (HideMessageButton.isChecked()) {  
             //HideMessageButton.setChecked(true);  
                PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.google.android.talk",
                          "com.google.android.talk.LAUNCHER"),
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

            } else { 

                HideMessageButton.setChecked(false);  
            }
         }
```

In my Manifest.xml

```
 package="com.example.hideapp"
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.talk"
        android:label="@string/talk" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.talk.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.talk.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I doubt the possibility of disabling an `activity` of another application from yours.

Comment: Is that for a custom launcher app? If that's so, please do not change other applications' enabled state. Users should always be able to see all applications (with launcher category intent) once they switch to other launcher. Please keep hidden apps list internally in your launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are wrong.
You have set the Intent category as class name.

It's `new ComponentName(String pkg, String clss)`. Where:

- `pkg` is the target package, i'm not sure, what it is in your case, it's not shown in your part of the `AndroidManifest.xml`
- `clss` is the target class, in your case `com.google.android.talk`

Comment: Ah ok this helps a bit already. 
 Here is the package="com.example.hideapp"